# Is unit testing in an order discouraged?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

I have a large program that I need to write tests for.  I'm wondering if it would be wrong to write tests that run in a specific order, as some necessarily have to run in order and that depend upon a previous test.

For example a scenario like the following:

- CreateEmployer

  - CreateEmployee (requires employer)
  - Add Department

The drawback I see to this approach is that if one test fails, all the of the follow tests will also fail.  But, I am going to have to write the code to build the database anyway, so it might be a more effective approach to use the code that builds the mock database as a sort of integration-like unit test.

Should I create the database without using the tests as a seed method, and then run each of the methods again to see the result? The problem I see with this approach is that if the seed method does not work all of the tests will fail and it won't be immediately clear that the error is in the seed method and not the services or the tests themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is discouraged.  Tests shouldn't be "temporally coupled".

Each test should run in complete isolation of other tests.  If you find yourself in a situation where the artifacts created by Test A are needed by Test B then you have two problems to correct:

- Test A shouldn't be creating artifacts (or side-effects).
- Test B should be using mock data as part of its "arrange" step.

Basically, the unit tests shouldn't be using a real database.  They should be testing the logic of the code, not the interaction with the infrastructure dependencies.  Mock those dependencies in order to test just the code.

Comment: Makes sense. I guess what I am describing would be more of an integration test.  Give that unit tests don't test interaction with the database and only logic, I can think of few places where I really need tests.  It seems wasteful to test what are essentially setter functions  `this.Department = foo`.  I'd say about 2% of my code has logic that is not trivial.

Comment: @RaySülzer: Well, you wouldn't *directly* test simple setters. You'd test business operations, and the logic being performed in those operations would invoke the setters. (If they *don't* invoke the setters then none of your business operations *use* those setters and the setters should be removed from the code entirely.) For integration tests, you'd want to remove the logic from the tests entirely and test only the integration points themselves (DAL operations, generally). There are some options there, depending on what works for your team. But the temporal coupling should still be removed.

Comment: Thanks!  Most of my service calls are simple setters than invoke _orm.Update(object).  Only a few of my functions truly require business logic that would need to be united tested.  It's a pretty basic program.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bad idea to have unit tests depend upon each other. In your example you could have a defect in both CreateEmployer and AddDepartment, but when all three fail because of the CreateEmployer test you might mistakenly assume that only the CreateEmployer test is 'really' failing. This means you've lost the potently valuable information that AddDepartment is failing as well.

Another problem is that you might create a separate workflow in the future that calls AddDepartment without calling CreateEmployer. Now your tests assume that CreateEmployer will always be called, but in reality it isn't. All three tests could pass, but the application could still break because you have a dependency you didn't know was there.

The best tests won't rely on a database at all, but will instead allow you to manually specify or "Mock" the data. Then you don't have to worry about an unrelated database problem breaking all of your tests.

Answer (score 1):

If these are truly Unit tests then yes, requiring a specific order is a bad practice for several reasons.

1. Coupling - As you point out, if one test fails, then subsequent ones will fail as well.  This will mask real problems.
2. TDD - A core principle of TDD is make tests easy to run.  If you do so, developers are more likely to run them.  If they are hard to run (e.g. I have to run the entire suite), then they are less likely to be run and their value is lost.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, unit tests should not depend upon the completion of another test in order to run. It is also hard to run them in a given sequence, but that may depend upon your unit testing tool.

In your example, I would create a test that tests the CreateEmployer method and makes sure it returns a new object the way you expect.

The second test I would create would be CreateEmployee, and if that test requires an Employer object, using dependency injection, your CreateEmployee method could receive its Employer object. Here is where you would use a mock object (one that code to get created, returning a fixed/known Employer) as the Employer object the CreateEmployee method would consume. This lets you test the CreateEmployee method and its actions upon that object, with a given/known instance of the Employer object.

Your third test, AddDepartment, I assume also depends upon an Employer object. This unit test can follow the same pattern, and receive a mock Employer object to consumer during its test. (The same object you pass to unit test two above.)

Each test now runs/fails on its own, and can run in any sequence.